# Prove that $f(A_1 \setminus A_2) \supseteq f(A_1) \setminus f(A_2)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> I have to prove that $f(A_1 \setminus A_2) \supseteq f(A_1) \setminus f(A_2)$.

My attempt:

Take $y \in f(A_1) \setminus f(A_2)$, then $y$ doesn't belong to $f(A_2)$. So $x = f^{-1}(y)$ doesn't belong to $A_2$, but $x \in A_1$. That is $x \in A_1 \setminus A_2$. Therefore, $x \in f(A_1 \setminus A_2)$ and so we have that $f(A_1 \setminus A_2) \supseteq f(A_1) \setminus f(A_2)$.

Now I have to Provide examples in which the inclusion is strict, meaning that the above property fails to be equal. Any examples please?

Comment: Since \ is used for $\rm\LaTeX$ macros, it won't render by itself for internal self-consistency. For sets, you want \setminus anyway ($A\setminus B$). For a regular backslash, try \backslash ($A \backslash B$). The spacing is a bit odd with \backslash for set difference, whereas \setminus is the preferred.

Comment: The problem here is that $f$ is not stipulated to be 1-1.

Answer (score 1):

Consider case when $A_1 \setminus A_2$ is not empty but images of $A_1$ and $A_2$ are equal (for example, constant functions) would do the stuff.

Simple example: $f(x)=x^2, A_1 = [-2, -1], A_2 = [1, 2]$ \
So we have
$$f(A_1) \setminus f(A_2) = \emptyset \subset f(A_1 \setminus A_2) = f([-2,1])$$
(since $f(A_1) = f(A_2)$)

Answer (score 1):

Another example. Let $A_1=\{1,2\},A_2=\{1\}$, and $f:A_1\to\{3\}:1,2\mapsto 3$. Then, $f(A_1)=f(A_2)$, so that $f(A_1)\setminus f(A_2)=\emptyset$, but $f(A_1\setminus A_2)=f(\{2\})=\{3\}$.

Comment: Basically, something weird happens when more than one element maps to the same element